# Count rows in dataframe for multiple variables

Tags: r, dataframe

I wish to count the number of rows that meet a certain condition (for a,b and c), whilst also remembering the values for d and e and summing them. For example:

Start dataset (df1):

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(
 a = sample(1:10,10,T),
 b = sample(1:13,10,T),
 c = sample(1:5,10,T),
 d = sample(c(0,1),10,T),
 e = sample(c(0,1),10,T))
df1 <- rbind(df1, c(3,3,5,1,1))
```

End dataset (df2):

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
  dplyr::count(a, b, c, name = 'count_abc') 

df2 <- data.frame(df2, count_d = c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1), count_e = c(1,2,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0))
```

Note: I manually added a row to df1 to demonstrate how matching rows should be dealt with

Comment: You `df2` example throws error. Are you looking something like `df1 %>% group_by(a, b, c) %>% summarise(cnt = n(), sum_d = sum(d), sum_e = sum(e))`?

Comment: Is it because you do not have the dplyr package installed? The count function relies upon it. I've updated the code with the library.

Comment: No I have the package installed :) . Check it again. I am sure you will see what is happening. Whe you `rbind` an extra row in df1, it does not create any duplicates as you think. The combination `3 3 5` does not exist prior to your rbind. So `count` gives result a df with 11 unique rows, which you are trying to bind with two vectors of 10 elements each

Comment: I have tested the code and it works for me, did you perhaps miss the set.seed? However, I believe your code solves the problem anyway so thank you :)

Comment: Yes I have included the `set.seed` . Anyway, I ll post it as answer since it helps you

Comment: If you highlight the whole first block and run it together I believe it should work? Regardless, thank you for the help, I'll be sure to mark your answer as the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can avoid `count()` and do the counting a bit manually, i.e.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
 group_by(a, b, c) %>% 
 summarise(cnt = n(), 
           sum_d = sum(d), 
           sum_e = sum(e))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after? The rowSums function can be used to sum specific columns and create a new column.

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(
  a = sample(1:10,10,T),
  b = sample(1:13,10,T),
  c = sample(1:5,10,T),
  d = sample(c(0,1),10,T),
  e = sample(c(0,1),10,T))
df1 <- rbind(df1, c(3,3,5,1,1))

library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>%
  dplyr::count(a, b, c, name = 'count_abc') 

# sums the d and e columns from df1
df2$de_sums <- rowSums(df1[,c(4,5)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although it doesn't quite work as intended, an example of the solution can be found by Sotos :)